# How to read all images from subfolder, resize them and save them with their original name in Python?

Tags: python

How to read all images from subfolder, resize them and save them with their original name in Python? Please help me. I want to read all images, which in different subfolder and want resize them and save them with their original name of images.

```
from PIL import Image

import os

path = "C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/Face Recognition using cnn/Face_database"

size = 112

def resize_images():

    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for item in dirs:
        if item == '.jpg':
            continue
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            image = Image.open(path+item)
            file_path, extension = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            image = image.resize((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image.save(file_path + "_resized" + extension, 'JPEG', quality=90)

resize_images()
```

Comment: give us some code to work with, what have you already tried? what are you struggling with?...

Comment: Generally, multi-step questions like this with little to no effort shown receive little to no help on Stackoverflow. It is not obvious if you have at all attempted this task and there is a specific part you are having trouble with, or if you are simply seeking for someone else to accomplish this for you.

Comment: sorry! i already edited question. In face_databae folder have 5 subfolders. I want to read all images from subfolder and resize them and then want to save with their original images name. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore or dashes but avoid white-spaces for directory names. To go through folders and sub-folders to discover files, I would recommend you make use of `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`. This may lead to a lot of nested `fors` but it should get the job done

```
from PIL import Image
import fnmatch
import os

thumbnail = (112,112)

def resize_images(path,size):

    dirs = os.walk(path)
    for folders in dirs:
        for files in folders:
            for file in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(*jpeg):
                    image = Image.open(item)
                    image = image.resize(size)
                    image.save(f"item{_resized}")
                else:
                    continue


resize_images("C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_using_cnn/Face_database", thumbnail)
```

An alternative to this level of nested for loops would be to make use of the `map()` higher order function.
Of course you will have to make some alterations to fit your folder and directory structure